# Quick press publish post hook

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

To execute a function during publishing post publish_post action hook is used. But what is quick press post publish hook?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Quick Edit" on the admin page post list-- `wp-admin/edit.php`?

Comment: No brother. I am talking about quick press by which authors/contributors can post from dashboard index.php page.

Comment: Quickpress is just a  widget that uses `post.php`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Wyck said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109961/quick-press-publish-post-hook/110943#comment153501_109961), it's just a [form that uses `post.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L459). To check if QuickPress is the one making the call use:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'check_for_quickpress_wpse_109961' ); 

function check_for_quickpress_wpse_109961( $post_id ) 
{
    if( 'post-quickpress-publish' == $_POST['action'] )
    {
        // do_something();
    }
}
```